# Как мне сделать, чтобы файл которые я поставил в значениях, он загружался в том же месте?

Tags: inno-setup

Как мне сделать чтобы файлы загрузались в том же месте где я указывал как файлы, которые он будет загружать?

PNG:
[image: PNG]

Код:

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{317027A4-7020-4373-9749-A97E2E7E2127}
AppName=ELauncher - patcher
AppVersion=1.5
;AppVerName=ELauncher - patcher 1.5
AppPublisher=Escape-World, Inc.
AppPublisherURL=http://escape-world.space
AppSupportURL=http://escape-world.space
AppUpdatesURL=http://escape-world.space
CreateAppDir=no
LicenseFile=C:\Users\Fps_M\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Lisance.txt
OutputDir=C:\Users\Fps_M\OneDrive\Рабочий стол
OutputBaseFilename=ELauncher - patcher
SetupIconFile=C:\Users\Fps_M\Downloads\minecraft_22400.ico
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"
Name: "russian"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Russian.isl"

[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\fps_m\AppData\Roaming\.tlauncher\legacy\Minecraft\game\*"; DestDir: "{win}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files
```